# Put jsonArray to SharedPreferenses

Tags: android, arrays, sharedpreferences

I am new in programming and need your help. I have sharedPreferenses that I am use in a few activities in my application. I use it for saving username, password and so on. Now I need to save into it tasks(Strings). But the problem is that I could`t understand how I can save a few tasks in the shared preferenses. Code that I have now save only the last task I put.

```
public class MainPage extends AppCompatActivity {
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    EditText input;
    Button btnDel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        prefs = getSharedPreferences("myUsers",MODE_PRIVATE);
        input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtItem);



        protected void SavePreferences1(String task) {
            JSONObject ExistUser = getUserByName("katya");//one of the users saved into sharedPreferences. 
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
                ExistUser.put("tasks", task);
                jsonArray.put(task);
                prefs.edit().putString(ExistUser.getString("name"), ExistUser.toString()).commit();//save changed JSON
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    public void SavePreferences(View v){

        SavePreferences1(input.getText().toString());
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharedPreferences can only store one value per key. `SavePreferences1` only has one array that's recreated every time it is called, and only has one task.

You ideally shouldn't use SharedPreferences for lists of data, anyway. A sqlite database would be preferred.

---

Though you could do something like

1. Get User Task list. Let this be `JSONArray tasks`

   - If User does not exist, get an empty task list `[]`. This can be specified by the default parameter of the `SharedPreferences` methods.
   - If User does exist, you have a list `[1, 2, 3...]`.
2. Add a new Task with `tasks.put(newTask)`
3. Put Username back into SharedPreferences with the updated task list. This will overwrite the existing task list for that user.

---

Easier way - Use Gson to give your `User` class a JSON representation you can serialize & deserialize to and from Java objects. Use an `ArrayList` like normal.

Comment: Thanks. But I still prefer to use SharedPreferences. Now I records in SheredPreferences that look like this: <string name="nikita">{“name”:”nikita”,”pass”:”112233qW”,”email”:”nikita@nikita.com”,”status”:true,”tasks”:”here”}</string> I just need to find way to put more tasks in Shared preferences.

Comment: What he is trying to say: you override your task, if you store the task everytime with the same username.

Comment: @KeitL You have no array in that data. `”tasks”:”‌​here”`... that's a string

Comment: Could you clarify what is not working in the other answer? `getString` is a method of the `JSONObject` and `SharedPreferences` class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protected void SavePreferences1(String task) {
            JSONObject ExistUser = getUserByName("katya");//one of the users saved into sharedPreferences. 
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(prefs.getString(ExistUser.getString("name"), "[]"));
                ExistUser.put("tasks", task);
                jsonArray.put(task);

                prefs.edit().putString(ExistUser.getString("name"), jsonArray.toString()).commit();//save changed JSON
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Thank you. But than I put this optString is highlighted in red. Than changed it on putString button is stoped working.

Comment: Try it with getString